# Why would Firefox be handling CSS padding differently from Safari or Chrome?

Tags: css

I have a little div with a number inside of it.
Firefox displays it differently from Safari or Chrome.

Here is what Safari displays:
[image]

And here is what Firefox displays: [image]

The CSS is this:

```
background: red; 
height: 20px;   
width: 20px; 
float: left; 
margin: 7px; 
padding-top: 0px; 
color: white; 
text-align: center;
```

Why is this happening? What can I do to prevent it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: When I run that CSS in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrkJN/) in both Chrome and Firefox, the box looks (close enough to be) identical. It could be some `line-height` parameter from a parent element interfering, or it could just be some font padding anomaly.

Comment: it's work me also. If it's still create problem then you css reset for this because every browser rendered elements differently.

Comment: Try explicitly declaring vertical-align: top;

Comment: Even from the screen you have shown of `padding-top: 0px` I say firefox is doing what it was suppose to do, unlike what safari is not.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the line height and the margins of the text itself.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your message. Unfortunately, setting the line-height doesn't seem to solve it, because it equally affects both browsers. I am still looking into it. Thanks again